# How can I pause/unpause a live recording programmatically on asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami, asterisk-ari

First of all I need to get a list of current live calls and then I need to pause and unpause the live recording pragmatically using asterisk ARI,AMI , anything that can achieve what I need

anyone has a clue what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk have nothing to do with your playback.

Asterisk is pbx. You can DOWNLOAD recording. Doesn't metter if your browser/app play it or show as "downloaded", on asterisk side it will be DOWNLOAD.

So you have deal with it on your side.

If you want pause playback in Dialplan(via phone), use ControlPlayback app.

There are no current calls tracking, asterisk track only channels. For see it use AMI command

```
COMMAND core show channels
```

You can do current calls tracking using dialplan+db.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,yeah they are currently doing it via the phone by pressing a certain key but is there a way to do it pragmatically perhaps by simulating the phone press on this channel or i am just talking nonsense :)

Comment: Yes, you can use AMI SendDTMF action or change code of app_controlplayback.c

Comment: that's what i am currently trying to do using Asterisk ARI on an active channel , i am using the c# wrapper but i am getting Forbidden response ,any thoughts what may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can definietly do this with AMI if you know the Channel ID.

```
asterisk*cli> manager show command PauseMonitor
[Syntax]
Action: PauseMonitor
[ActionID:] <value>
Channel: <value>

asterisk*cli> manager show command UnpauseMonitor
[Syntax]
Action: UnpauseMonitor
[ActionID:] <value>
Channel: <value>
```